# Debug "Could not load class" fatal error in Contao CMS

Tags: php, class, namespaces, contao

I get in my **Contao 2.11.11** installation with the module **[MetaModels 1.0.x](https://now.metamodel.me/en/resources/nightly-builds?file=files/nightlies/nightly-contao3.tar.bz2)** the error:

> Fatal error: Could not load class MetaModels\Attribute\TranslatedReference

I could narrow the problem down to the file `system/modules/metamodelsattribute_translatedcombinedvalues/MetaModels/Attribute/TranslatedCombinedValues/TranslatedCombinedValues.php`

There first the `namespace` is set and then the class `TranslatedReference` is called, which created the fatal error.

```php
namespace MetaModels\Attribute\TranslatedCombinedValues;

use MetaModels\Attribute\TranslatedReference;
use MetaModels\Helper\ContaoController;

class TranslatedCombinedValues extends TranslatedReference
{
 // ...
}
```

**How can I debug why the class couldn't be called.**

Comment: What's the full path to TranslatedReference.php, and what namespace is defined at the top of that file?

Comment: I can only find the file `system/modules/metamodels/MetaModelAttributeTranslatedReference.php` that's what I was wondering too. You can see it in [github](https://github.com/backbone87/metamodels-core/blob/master/src/system/modules/metamodels/MetaModelAttributeTranslatedReference.php)

Comment: Strange.. I can't find `TranslatedCombinedValues` in the .tar.bz2 you linked to.

Comment: @NateB thx for the help, it seems that I had just to call the right class name. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34171732/3001970)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently as the `namespace` was okay I just had to call the correct class name:

```
namespace MetaModels\Attribute\TranslatedCombinedValues;

//use MetaModels\Attribute\TranslatedReference;
//use MetaModels\Helper\ContaoController;
use MetaModelAttributeTranslatedReference;

//class TranslatedCombinedValues extends TranslatedReference
class TranslatedCombinedValues extends MetaModelAttributeTranslatedReference
{
 // ...
}
```